# Generic variable inside generic class returns empty

Tags: generics, swiftui

When the getUserDefaults function works, when I call the "allQuestionList" variable inside the other view, it returns empty.
What is the reason of this ?
I want T to assign whatever model I give it to "allQuestionList".

```
class UserDefaultsStore<T: Codable>: ObservableObject {

    @Published var allQuestionList: T?
    
    func setUserDefaults(forkey key: String) {
        let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
        if let encoded = try? jsonEncoder.encode(allQuestionList) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: key)
        }
    }
    
    func getUserDefaults(forKey key: String) {
        if let questions = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: key) {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            if let decode = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: questions) {
                self.allQuestionList = decode
            }
        }
    }
    
    func removeUserDefaults(forKey key: String) {
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: key)
    }
    
    func isKeyPresentInUserDefaults(key: String) -> Bool {
        return UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) != nil
    }
}
```

**Example:**

Let's take the User model for example.

If I run the application without assigning the User model, then it returns null. Whenever I assign a value when the application is opened, then it returns a full value.

```
Nil -> @Published var userQuestions: User?
```

However, the variable here is successfully assigned.

```
class UserDefaultsStore<T: Codable>: ObservableObject {
    @Published var userQuestions: User = User(uid: "", questions: UserQuiz(title: "", test: []), wrongQuestions: [])
    .....
}
```

**User Model:**

```
struct User: Codable {
    var uid: String
    var questions: UserQuiz?
    var wrongQuestions: [UserQuestionList]?
}

struct UserQuiz: Codable {
    var title: String?
    var test: [UserQuestionList]?
}

struct UserQuestionList: Codable {
    var id: Int?
    var question: String?
    var isQuestionImage, isSectionImage: Bool?
    var imageURL: String?
    var sections: [UserQuestionSections.RawValue : String]?
    var selected: String?
    var correct: String?
}

enum UserQuestionSections: String, Codable, Hashable {
    case A = "A"
    case B = "B"
    case C = "C"
    case D = "D"
}
```

**Quiz Model:**

```
struct QuizContainer: Codable, Hashable {
    var allQuiz: [Quiz]?
}

struct Quiz: Codable, Hashable {
    var title: String?
    var id: String
}
```

**Example:**

I use it this way, but the variable allQuestionList returns empty to me.

```
struct QuestionListView: View {
    ...
    @EnvironmentObject var userDefaultsStore: UserDefaultsStore<User>
    ...
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
        

          ForEach(userDefaultsStore.allQuestionList?.questions?.test?.indices ?? 0..<0, id: \.self) { index in {
...
}


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I have spent more than 5 minutes reading this question but I don’t understand what you are asking or how the class UserDefaultsStore is supposed to be used.

Comment: allQuestionList gives me null value. How can I make this generic? Whatever model I give T, I want it to populate the allQuestionList variable with that model. Sorry. I know little English.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I edited my question sir. I added Example

Comment: And how do you set allQuestionList? Honestly I don’t see how allQuestionList belongs to the class UserDefaultsStore, it is a very strange solution

Comment: How can I make this code generic sir. ?

Answer (score -2):

I solved my problem.

```
class UserDefaultsStore<T: Decodable>: ObservableObject {
    @Published var userQuestions: T?
    
    func setUserDefaults(forkey key: String, forModel model: T) where T: Encodable {
        let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
        if let encoded = try? jsonEncoder.encode(model) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: key)
        }
    }
    
    func getUserDefaults(forKey key: String, forModel model: T.Type) -> Void {
        if let questions = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: key) {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            if let decode = try? decoder.decode(model, from: questions) {
                self.userQuestions = decode
            }
        }
    }
    
    func removeUserDefaults(forKey key: String) {
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: key)
    }
    
    func isKeyPresentInUserDefaults(key: String) -> Bool {
        return UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) != nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Fine but the property userQuestions in that class makes no sense since it is not related to any of the functions of the class. It should be stored elsewhere

Comment: Should I remove the userQuestions property from this class?